# keeping the navigation link active

Tags: jquery, css

what is the problem in the code its not working and also i have checked other methods but still the same problem.

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
      $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        
    });
```

```css
.active   
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03B003;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/work">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/resume">Resume</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Define an "active" link please (see answer below, it doesn't seem to correspond to the `:active` selector).

Comment: To be clear: did you add jquery library to your code?

Comment: yes i added but problem is different

Comment: Is it something you want to have? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZBBZZ

Comment: yes bro excatly the same but it doesnt work with the page,actually it blocks me to get to the required page

Comment: it is not that simple if you want it to work with reload browser window content, because all classes you add to the link will be cleared after load new page, so the only one solution is to after each page load check for each nav links which one has link for current website and add 'active' class to it. I will try to write some code for you.

Comment: thanks bro i didnt knew it, thatswhy the code is not working, all these code are for single window navigation.

Comment: thanks bro for telling me the actual problem, i found the answer @joint

Comment: great then, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code, which should work in your case, but only if you have urls with '/something'. For better try modify by yourself ;)

```
$(function() {
    var currentPage = window.location.href;
    var urlParts = currentPage.split('/');
    var searchFor = '/' + urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
    $('.nav-list a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == searchFor) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using :active property of CSS.
a:active {Do something;}
You don't need jQuery for this simple code

Comment: can you tell me how to do?

Comment: a:active   
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03B003;
    background-color: red;
} Put this in your CSS file and the property will apply to the link which is active

Comment: Try to refreshing stylesheet. If you will not forcibly refresh the stylesheet it will then take time the changes to appear

Comment: @RaashidDinDar link is ':active' only when you press mouse button, but it will disappear when you release the button, it is not what he want to achieve

Comment: bro i'm not getting you @joint can you help me with this

Comment: @joint use : focus property with active property e.g;a:active,a:focus{do whatever you want}

Comment: @joint for your kind information the active link will remain activeonce the user is on it

Comment: Kundan did you refreshed stylesheet

Comment: @RaashidDinDar still not what he want, when you click somewhere on the content then your focus is not on the link, Kundan Kumar tell me what is the goal you want to achieve? Links should load other page with http request or not? If yes, then adding 'active' have no sense, because after load new page your link will lost this class.

Comment: yes i did but nothing is working, yes bro new page will load, see actually i'm using header in all my pages thatswhy every page is getting link of all the css and js files

Comment: Kundan you lost me (reference to your previous comment).

Comment: i think there is bug in my code thatswhy none of these methods are working actually there is more that 100lines of code

Comment: `:active` is only triggered by clicking the element and doesn't keep the url active

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it with plain old JS without jQuery

```js
// Get all elements
var urls = document.getElementsByClassName('url');

// Make sure there are elements
if( urls )
{
  // For each element
  for( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ )
  {
    var url = urls[i];
    
    // Add an event to a element
    url.addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {
      // Check if a class is already set on a element and peform action based on that
      if( e.target.classList.contains( 'active' ) )
      {
        e.target.classList.remove( 'active' );
      } else {
        e.target.classList.add( 'active' );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.active   
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03B003;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url">Projects</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url">Resume</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or just set the active class for each page:

```css
.active   
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03B003;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url active">Portfolio</a><!-- Set active class when on this page -->
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url">Projects</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="url">Resume</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will you take a look on my code, hope so after that you could help me

Comment: i did but the problem is still there

Comment: @KundanKumar if you didn't remove that piece of JS/jQuery that you used in the question than no it doesn't work. You don't need that piece of JS for both examples in the answer.

Comment: already removed, actually the active class gets added when i click the navigation link but when the page gets loaded the active class disappers

Comment: @KundanKumar that is why I said add the `active` class on every page in the menu on the page that is active like in the last example